# Adding "in" part to tactic to specify where to apply it

Tags: coq, ltac

I am new to Coq and to writing tactics, and I have been unable to figure out whether you can define more complicated tactics like the build in ones. For example, say that I have a tactic `tac1` taking two arguments, and I define `tac2` by

```
Ltac tac2 arg := tac1 arg _.
```

Then this works as I would expect, but I would really like to be able to call `tac2` on a hypothesis, like `tac2 arg in H`.  I can see that I can just give the hypothesis as an extra argument, but then I cannot use it in the goal, and I would also like to be able to use it like `tac2 arg in *`.

Is something like that possible, and how would it be accomplished?

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159010/1529157) about how you add intro patterns to tactics you define, and it lead me to [this page](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#tactic-notations) about `Tactic Notation`, but I am unable to figure out from that if what I would like is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842382/7508402), you may define notations for tac2 like this:

```
Tactic Notation "tac2" constr(arg) :=
  tac1 arg _.

Tactic Notation "tac2" constr(arg) "in" hyp(H) :=
  tac1 arg _ in H.

Tactic Notation "tac2" constr(arg) "in" "*" :=
  repeat match goal with
         | H:_ |- _ => tac2 arg in H
         | |- _ => tac2 arg
         end.
```

Of course, `tac1` needs to work with an `in` modifier and you should be careful with the termination of the `repeat` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536938/7508402)).